# How to insert a value into a URL to make a request to YQL

Tags: ios, swift, yql

I'm running into a problem when I try to make a request to YQL for stock data, when the symbol (`newCompanyStockSymbol`) to look up is user-entered. I fetch the stocks in this function:

```
func handleSave() {

    // Fetch stock price from symbol provided by user for new company
    guard let newCompanyStockSymbol = stockTextField.text else {
        print("error getting text from field")
        return
    }
    var newCompanyStockPrice = ""

    let url = URL(string: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20symbol%2C%20Ask%2C%20YearHigh%2C%20YearLow%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22\(newCompanyStockSymbol)%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            let json = JSON(data: data!)
            if let quotes = json["query"]["results"]["quote"].array {
                for quote in quotes {
                    let ask = quote["Ask"].stringValue
                    newCompanyStockPrice = ask
                }
            }
            print("new company json: \(json)")
        }
        guard let newCompanyName = self.nameTextField.text else {
            print("error getting text from field")
            return
        }
        guard let newCompanyLogo = self.logoTextField.text else {
            print("error getting text from field")
            return
        }
        print("2: The new commpany stock price is: \(newCompanyStockPrice)")

        // Call save function in view controller to save new company to core data
        self.viewController?.save(name: newCompanyName, logo: newCompanyLogo, stockPrice: newCompanyStockPrice)
        self.viewController?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    task.resume()

    // Present reloaded view controller with new company added
    let cc = UINavigationController()
    let companyController = CompanyController()
    viewController = companyController
    cc.viewControllers = [companyController]
    present(cc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And I use string interpolation to insert `\(newCompanyStockSymbol)` into the request URL at the appropriate place. However I get a crash and error on that line because it's returning nil, I expect because it's using the URL with `\(newCompanyStockSymbol)` in there verbatim, instead of actually inserting the value.

Is there another way to do this?

EDIT

[image]

And the `save` function in view controller that's called from `handleSave()` above if it's helpful:

```
func save(name: String, logo: String, stockPrice: String) {

    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Company",
                                   in: managedContext)!
    let company = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                  insertInto: managedContext)


    company.setValue(stockPrice, forKey: "stockPrice")
    company.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    company.setValue(logo, forKey: "logo")


    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        companies.append(company)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Callam unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional value

Comment: highlighting the `let url` line. And in my console it shows that `newCompanyStockPrice` is still an empty string, even though I tried to set `ask` to that variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you entered AAPL in your stockTextField, using simply:

```
    let newCompanyStockSymbol = stockTextField.text
```

results in newCompanyStockSymbol being:

```
    Optional("AAPL")
```

which is not what you want in your URL string. The critical section ends up like this:

```
    (%22Optional("AAPL")%22)
```

Instead, use guard to get the value from the text field:

```
    guard let newCompanyStockSymbol = stockTextField.text else {
        // handle the error how you see fit
        print("error getting text from field") 
        return
    }
```

Now your URL should be parsed correctly.

--- Additional info ---

I'm not entirely sure of the rules on 'continued conversation' around here, but hopefully editing this will be acceptable... anyway...

Make sure you are following this flow:

```
func handleSave() {

    let newCompanyName = nameTextField.text
    let newCompanyStockSymbol = stockTextField.text
    let newCompanyLogo = logoTextField.text

    var newCompanyStockPrice = ""

    // Fetch stock price from symbol provided by user for new company
    let url = URL(string: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20symbol%2C%20Ask%2C%20YearHigh%2C%20YearLow%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22\(newCompanyStockSymbol)%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            let json = JSON(data: data!)
            if let quotes = json["query"]["results"]["quote"].array {
                for quote in quotes {
                    let ask = quote["Ask"].stringValue
                    newCompanyStockPrice = ask

                    // task completed, we've parsed the return data, 
                    // so NOW we can finish the save process and 
                    // update the UI

                    viewController?.save(name: newCompanyName!, logo: newCompanyLogo!, stockPrice: newCompanyStockPrice)

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()        
}
```

I'm not testing this, so it might need a tweak, and your .save() function may need to be forced onto the main thread (since it's doing UI updates). But maybe that's a little more clear.

Comment: Oh, that would explain it! Thanks, I'm not getting the crash now. However when I set a breakpoint to the line where I save the fetched stock price (`viewController?.save(name: newCompanyName!, logo: newCompanyLogo!, stockPrice: newCompanyStockPrice)`), I see that newCompanyStockPrice is still an empty string, so I don't think the data is getting fetched correctly. I added a screenshot of the console to my post.

Comment: `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)` is an async task - it starts when you call `task.resume()` but then execution continues immediately to your save function, where you pass a non-changed newCompanyStockPrice variable. You want to call your save function from within your completion handler **after** processing HTTPURLResponse and setting newCompanyStockPrice.

Comment: Moving the save function inside the completion handler, directly before `task.resume()` (inside the closing brace of the completion handler, after the `else if let` closing brace) still doesn't work unfortunately. I also tried putting it everywhere in between and the new company still isn't set/appearing on my table view. I can make another question if you feel like you know the answer, this is pretty frustrating! I feel like I'm so close yet so far. The newCompanyStockPrice now has a value, but I think it's not getting saved properly because it's not showing up on my table view.

Comment: If you're still having troubles with this, I posted a simple example project at https://github.com/DonMag/YQLTest

Comment: I tried your edited code and the values are not saved correctly - I edited my code in my question to show what works for me in terms of properly saving the user-entered values into core data and having them successfully show up on my tableview - however the stock price for the user-entered company still does not work. It appears that my for loop doesn't even get called.. putting a breakpoint on the `for quote in quotes` line does not interrupt the program.

Comment: Did you take a look at the sample I put up? Your code right before that line is: `if let quotes = json["query"]["results"]["quote"].array {` ... however, that results in nil, so it will never reach the `for quote in quotes` block.

Comment: You are correct, I tried your approach in the sample and it's working now. Thanks for your help!